# EC2Launch v2 Initializing Disks for Windows

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Not exactly sure how AWS imagined the Engineers going from EC2Launch v1 to EC2Launch v2... it might be the solution in the long term but atm idk. Struggling to find useful documentation on how to interact with EC2Launch v2. I digress.

**Context**:
I'm attempting to Launch a WS2022 Server using a CloudFormation Script with mutliple hardrives. I hope to automate it's initialization using a `AWS::SSM::Document` resource.

**Problem**
When the WS2022 Server Comes online you have to manually initialize the additional HDD's with Disk Manager.

**Wanted Outcome**
A WS2022 Server with multiple hard drives accessible on first time bootup.

**What I've Done**

- Attempted to use the gui `AWS EC2 Launch` and initialize the HDD. ( no success )
- I'm in the process of rewriting a `EC2Launch v1` script `InitializeDisk.ps1` that can hopefully be thrown into an S3 bucket and be executed by `SSMDocument` at a later date.

Cloud Formation Template Code:

```
# Don't worry about the Ref Variables as they are pretty generic. 

 #Create Instance
  WindowsServer2022Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      InstanceType: 'i3.large'
      ImageId:  #WS2022 AMI Image
      IamInstanceProfile: # Some InstanceProfile 
      EbsOptimized: true
      KeyName: 
        Ref: # Some KeyName
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - DeviceIndex: '0'
          SubnetId: # Some Subnet ID
          AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: # Some Subnet ID
        
  #EC2 Volume Creation
  AdditionalVolume:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Volume'
    Properties:
      Size: 100
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - 'WindowsServer2022Instance'
          - 'AvailabilityZone'
      VolumeType: 'gp3'
  #Attach EC2 Volume
  VolumeAttachment:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment'
    Properties:
      InstanceId:
        Ref: 'WindowsServer2022Instance'
      VolumeId:
        Ref: 'AdditionalVolume'
      Device: '/dev/sdf'
```